# Eliminar una fila de una sola tabla haciendo INNER JOIN de varias tablas

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**users**:

```
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| firstname      | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastname       | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| birthday       | datetime        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| email          | varchar(50)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| valid          | tinyint(1)      | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| validationCode | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| password       | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| reg_date       | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**courses**:

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| course_id   | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| course_name | varchar(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**subjects**:

```
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subject_id    | int(6) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject_name  | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teacher_name  | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject_room  | varchar(30)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject_color | varchar(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| course_id     | int(6) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es eliminar una asignatura de la tabla `subjects` sabiendo la **id del usuario** y el **nombre de la asignatura** que se desea eliminar, lo que tengo hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
$drop = $conn->prepare("
        DELETE subjects.*
        FROM subjects users
        INNER JOIN courses ON users.id = courses.user_id
        INNER JOIN subjects ON courses.course_id = subjects.course_id
        WHERE users.id = :userid AND subjects.subject_name = :subjectName
    ");
```

Haciendo esto, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> **Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause''**

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda....

Comment: por favor agrega el tag del motor de base de datos que estás usando

Comment: @Lamak ya está :)

Comment: Y por otro lado, creo que es bueno agradecer que te está tirando error, porque tus `INNER JOIN`s casi seguro **no** está entregando las filas que quieres borrar, sino que muchas más

Comment: Lo que agregaste no es el motor de base de datos. Me refiero a si estás usando mysql, postgresql, Oracle, SQL Server, etc

Comment: Tan solo quiero borrar una fila, y sí las entrega correctamente en otros scripts que tengo.

Comment: @Lamak el motor que estoy usando es mysql

Comment: Si estas usando el motor de **mysql** y tienes creados relaciones internas solo  con el borrado en cascada solo tienes que borrar el registro de la tabla padre y el se encarga de borrar las de tabla hijo.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez NO quiero borrar todo lo que contenga dentro, solo quiero borrar algo determinado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sentencia seria el siguiente:

```
DELETE s    
FROM users as u
INNER JOIN courses as c 
    ON u.id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN subjects as s 
    ON c.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE u.id = :userid AND s.subject_name = :subjectName
```

Espero te ayude mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Rostan :)